# simple 4-line C program with massive malloc only segfaults with Valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind

When the following is run without valgrind, I don't get a segfault.  When it's run with valgrind, I do.  It seems to be a result of the size of the malloc, because if I make it about 1/4 that size, it doesn't happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float *a = malloc(400000000 * sizeof(float));
    a[5] = 3.0;
    printf("%f\n", a[5]);
    free(a);
}
```

Here's the output from valgrind

```
==31972== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31972== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31972== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31972== Command: ./seg
==31972== 
==31972== Invalid write of size 4
==31972==    at 0x80484A5: main (seg.c:8)
==31972==  Address 0x5f5e0ffc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==31972== 
==31972== 
==31972== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==31972==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x5F5E0FFC
==31972==    at 0x80484A5: main (seg.c:8)
==31972==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==31972==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==31972==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==31972==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==31972==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==31972== 
==31972== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31972==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31972==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==31972== 
==31972== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31972== 
==31972== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31972== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

If I did the math right, that's about 1.5 GB of memory.

If I do the bash command `free -m` while **not** running it, it looks like I have about 2 GB of free ram.  Perhaps that's cutting it close?

Any thoughts?  Might it mean that I'm *'close'* to segfaulting **without** valgrind, if I malloced even more memory?

Comment: I'd say there is a problem of size of your array. Valgrind uses extra memory for its structures so the size of its structures plus your array are more than valgrind can handle.

Comment: Also I don't have any problems on my machine with your code and valgrind

Comment: @MichałWalenciak +1 for running it. Could you replicate the valgrind error message by increasing the memory to be malloc'd?

Comment: @bytefire: I can increase memory usage up to 800000000 floats and it is still ok. When I increased to 810000000 I got segfault because of access to 0x14 (malloc must have returned nullptr). Segfault occurs in both: normal run and valgrind run. I cannot reproduce difference between valgrind/non-valgrind run

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` attempts to allocate a *contiguous* block of memory. You might have 2GB free in your system *in total*, but chances are it does not exist in a single chunk. And that is the problem. I bet that if you actually checked, you would see that the memory allocation failed.

In that case you are attempting to access a `NULL` pointer on line 2.

According to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for `malloc`

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy.
>   This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee
>   that the memory really is available. In case it turns out that the
>   system is out of memory, one or more processes will be killed by the
>   OOM killer. For more information, see the description of
>   /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory and /proc/sys/vm/oom_adj in proc(5),
>   and the Linux kernel source file
>   Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting.

so I guess there is an additional element of unpredictability there.

Comment: I thought about it also, but it would give different message here:  `Address 0x5f5e0ffc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`

Comment: I was having this problem with an actual program I wrote, and when run without Valgrind, it didn't just not segfault, but it also worked (and the program entails read/write operations on every float in that block).

Comment: @user3391564: I cannot see any problem in your code (maybe except missing `if` statement for `a == 0` after malloc ;) )

Comment: @MichałWalenciak strange, but the Valdgrind docs state: *Note that Memcheck only tells you that your program is about to access memory at an illegal address. It can't stop the access from happening. So, if your program makes an access which normally would result in a segmentation fault, you program will still suffer the same fate.*

Comment: @dandan78: it may happen that you access the invalid (or rather unallocated) memory without crash. Usually access to unallocated pages causes segfault but you may be lucky to access unallocated memory on allocated page ;) It should not segfault your program but may destroy heap info or override areas of other variables you use.